# Microsoft Flow integration

Tags: power-automate

I read an article about Microsoft Flow. I was wondering if it is possible to trigger events using this in an external website.

For instance, supposing a post is made on Yammer for some approval flow based application. If an authorized user comments saying "Approved", this must trigger an action in my external website.

Is this feasible using Flow?

Answer (score 1):

You can also make your own custom connectors if your website has a RESTful API. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/flow/register-custom-api

Answer (score 0):

There is an event for Yammer in Microsoft flow.  I have something set up similar for my company and Twitter.  When our company is mentioned it sends a message off to our social director.

I have several such flows for things like Yelp, Twitter, Facebook.

You need your Yammer account.
The events that you can trigger from and then include a trigger word or phrase are:
Get All messages
Get Messages in a group
Get Messages from my Following Feed
Post Message

Once you have that trigger its simple enough to look for the key word within a condition step.

Chances are good there is already a template for this in Microsoft Flow.  Just look at the ones for Yelp, Facebook, etc. and modify for your needs

Comment: I'm aware of the current Yammer events. I was asking if we could integrate our own websites. My company creates their own websites, so Can this be integrated with Yammer?

Answer (score 0):

Just as AJAX mentioned, you can apply your own Custom Connector for a case like this. A Connector is the "plugin" used with a Flow, such as Yammer.

It's a bit late since November 28th (practically a 30-day late response here), but PowerApps allows you to create your own Custom Connector applying Microsoft's API. You'd be able to plug into your website (GET, POST, etc) directly with this when you create a trigger (the condition met true) that would launch an action. If you created your own API, Microsoft would have to validate if it's met standards pertaining to security.

By applying PowerApps, you'd be able to create your own actions and triggers. From this, you can integrate your own web based process' based on documentation that was observed: https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/brand-new-custom-api-experience-in-powerapps/. From here, you'd be able to customize it was needed.

JSON is required for some circumstances, however Postman would be a great IDE to consider as it also applies a pre-approved API by Micrsoft.