# How To Integrate Microsoft Flows

Tags: dynamics-crm, power-automate

I am creating Flows in https://flow.microsoft.com, 
I Don't know that How I can use or call these flow from my website. or how I can integrate it from my website.

What I want : I want to create these flow in my website and want users to select or create flows and then want to trigger these flow on some conditions.

So do I have to design this all in my website or I can integrate already created user flow in my website from 
https://flow.microsoft.com

Is there any api to integrate it? 
I want to integrate Dynamic 365 and sales force flows

I saw a thread [Microsoft Flow integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47299836/microsoft-flow-integration) But no answer here.

Please suggest what should I do to trigger flows from external websites.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to select "HTTP Request" as the trigger, and pass in a JSON object to start a Flow. This would enable you to call it from an external website with whatever parameters you want.

[image: HTTP Request]